# Eigendecomposition - Optimization of quadratic expressions

Tags: functions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reading [Deep Learning (page 44)](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/):

> The eigendecomposition of a real symmetric matrix can also be used to optimize quadratic expressions of the form $f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf {x^T  Ax}$ subject to $\|\mathbf x\|_2 = 1$. Whenever $\mathbf x$ is equal to an eigenvector of $\mathbf A$, $f$ takes on the value of the corresponding eigenvalue.
>
> The maximum value of $f$ within the constraint region is the maximum eigenvalue and its minimum value within the constraint region is the minimum eigenvalue.

The first part is clear to me, I can derive it with:

$$\mathbf {Ax} = \mathbf {\lambda x}$$
$$f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf {x^T  Ax}$$
$$\Rightarrow f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf {x^T  \lambda x}$$
$$\Rightarrow f(\mathbf x) = \lambda$$
since $\|x\|_2 = 1$.

However, I cannot understand why the maximum and the minimum value of $f$ correspond to the relative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $A$ is symmetric, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of $A$, i.e. there is $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $S^TAS=D$ and $S^TS=I$ and $$D = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}$$
(the eigenvalues in this matrix are not necessarily different from each other)

As $S$ is orthogonal, it preserves lengths and angles, therefore we have $\|S^Tx\|=\|x\|$.

We now look at $x^TAx$ for an arbitrary vector $x$ with $\|x\|=1$.
$$
x^TAx = x^TSDS^Tx = y^TDy = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2 \lambda_i
$$
with $y=S^Tx$ and $\|y\|=1$. As $\sum y_i^2 = 1$ and $y_i^2\geq 0$, we conclude that $x^TAx$ is a convex combination of the $\lambda_i$, i.e. its miminum value is the minimum eigenvalue of $A$ and its maximum value is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Curious if this derivation would still go through if you changed the norm to $\|x\|_{\infty}=1?$

Comment: I perform the substitution $y=S^Tx$ and use the fact that we still have $\|y\|=1,$ because orthogonal transformations preserve lengths. But orthogonal transformations do not preserve the value of $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}.$ Therefore, the derivation does not work in this case.

Comment: I think you could get bounds, though: if $\mathbf{x}$ has $n$ dimensions, then it is true, is it not, that $\|S^T\mathbf{x}\|_\infty\le\sqrt{n}\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty.$ Is that right?

Comment: Sure, we can get bounds. The inequality is correct. It is probably worth a separate question to clarify how exactly this results in bounds for $\min_{\|x\|_{\infty}=1} f(x)$ and $\max_{\|x\|_{\infty}=1} f(x).$