# Maximum amplitude of the fundamental of a discrete periodic signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I have a signal sampled on $n$ points which cover a period, and I determine the amplitude of the fundamental by convolving with cosinusoid and sinusoid samples.

$$C:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_k\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n},$$

$$S:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_k\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}.$$

I need to know the maximum value that can be taken by the modulus $\sqrt{C^2+S^2}$ when the $x_k$'s are bounded in range $[-M, M]$.

I can easily find the maximum of $C$ or $S$ separately, by setting $x_k=M$ for the positive $\cos$ (resp. $\sin$) and $x_k=-M$ otherwise. But I need to solve this for the sum of squares $C^2+S^2$. (An upper bound is $2M^2$, obviously, but it is not tight.)

Any hint ?

---

**Update:**

As shown by @Adrian,

$$C^2+S^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_kx_j\left(\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}\cos\frac{2\pi j}{n}+\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}\sin\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_kx_j\cos\frac{2\pi(k-j)}{n}.$$

This is a quadratic expression, which we have to maximize under the constraints $|x_k|\le M$.

Comment: Check out my edits?

Answer (score 1):

The key is this trig identity:
$$S=\sum_k x_k \sin(x+\theta_k)=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}x_i x_j \cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)}\,\sin\left(x+\arctan\left(\frac{\sum_k x_k\sin(\theta_k)}{\sum_k x_k\cos(\theta_k)}\right)\right), $$
which you can produce by combining the trig identities [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207111/eigendecomposition-optimization-of-quadratic-expressions). Similarly, you can show that
$$C=\sum_k x_k \cos(x+\theta_k)=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}x_i x_j \cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)}\,\cos\left(x+\arctan\left(\frac{\sum_k x_k\sin(\theta_k)}{\sum_k x_k\cos(\theta_k)}\right)\right). $$
Applying this to your problem, we find that $x=0,$ and
\begin{align*}
S^2&=\sum_{i,j}x_i x_j \cos\left(\frac{2\pi(i-j)}{n}\right)\sin^2(\alpha) \\
C^2&=\sum_{i,j}x_i x_j \cos\left(\frac{2\pi(i-j)}{n}\right)\cos^2(\alpha),
\end{align*}
where
$$\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac{\sum_k x_k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)}{\sum_k x_k \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)}\right) $$
It follows that
$$C^2+S^2=\sum_{i,j}x_i x_j \cos\left(\frac{2\pi(i-j)}{n}\right), $$
a nearly miraculous simplification, in my opinion. This is a quadratic expression that we can write as $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x},$ where
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&=\left[\begin{matrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_{n-1}\end{matrix}\right]\\
A_{ij}&=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(i-j)}{n}\right).
\end{align*}
Then [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207111/eigendecomposition-optimization-of-quadratic-expressions) comes into play, and the problem becomes one of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Because $\mathbf{A}$ is real and symmetric, it has an eigen-decomposition $\mathbf{SDS}^T,$ where $\mathbf{S}$ is orthogonal and $\mathbf{D}$ is diagonal. The crucial line of the answer there is that
$$\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{SDS}^T\mathbf{x} =\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{Dy} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2 \lambda_i. $$
If the $\mathbf{S}$ is just a rotation, then $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\infty}=M$ and $\|\mathbf{y}\|_{\infty}\le\sqrt{n}\,M,$ so that:
$$\max\!\left(C^2+S^2\right)\le nM^2\left[\sum_{\lambda>0}\lambda - \sum_{\lambda<0}\lambda\right]=nM^2\sum|\lambda|. $$

Comment: Interesting. In fact by directly expanding the squares and regrouping, one establishes your last identity directly. If I am right, the $(i,j)$ region where the cosine is positive is an hexagon, which must be covered by squares.

Comment: Yes, I've simplified my derivation a bit - no need to dive into expressions like $\sin(\arctan(x)).$

Comment: Yeah, so $\cos(x)$ is positive when $0\le x<\pi/2,$ and when $3\pi/2 < x\le 2\pi.$ Translating to the argument you actually have, you'd need \begin{align*} 0&\le \frac{2\pi(i-j)}{n}<\frac{\pi}{2} \quad\text{or}\\ \frac{3\pi}{2} &< \frac{2\pi(i-j)}{n}\le 2\pi.\end{align*} Might also have to look at $[-2\pi,0].$

Comment: Mh, how can $\|x\|_\infty=\|y\|_\infty$ with a rotation ? We do have $\|x\|_2=\|y\|_2$.

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right. Thinking...

Comment: Can you write $\|\mathbf{y}\|_\infty$ in terms of $\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty$ and $n?$

Comment: Right, I think you can say that $\|\mathbf{y}\|_\infty=\sqrt{n}\,M,$ in which case I've updated the answer.

Comment: How can you say that ? It depends on the Eigendecomposition of $A$, doesn't it ?

Comment: Hmm. I suppose all I've got is an upper bound: if $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{S}^T\mathbf{x}$ such that $\|\mathbf{y}\|_\infty=\sqrt{n}M,$ then it will actually be attained, but there's no guarantee.